# Existe alguma biblioteca específica para trabalhar com android e arduino?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

Estou com alguns projetos de automação, e queria desenvolver meu próprio app, que controlasse um arduino.
Com pouca pesquisa, percebi que existem várias ferramentas que criam essa comunicação e ainda te retornam um app pronto, porém, gostaria de desenvolver meu próprio app. Quero saber se existe alguma API própria para trabalhar com essa comunicação, ou se apenas envio comandos por bluetooth ou wifi e decifro esses comandos no próprio arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Podes comunicar com uma aplicação android através de um módulo Bluetooth como por exemplo o HC-06 ligada ao arduino. Essa aplicação poderá ser criada, por exemplo, com o [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) e uma livraria como a [BluetoothSerial](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial).

Para mais detalhes, por favor verifica a resposta que já dei a outra pergunta semelhante:

[Comunicação HC-06 com android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129542/comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-hc-06-com-android)