# Comunicação HC-06 com android

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

Olá, sou leigo no assunto e gostaria de saber como fazer, se possível, uma transferência de dados via bluetooth do Android para o módulo HC-06 do arduino utilizando o próprio pareamento do celular. Ou seja, como manipular apenas a programação de funções de envio/leitura de dados no Android e no Arduino para estabelecer a comunicação.
Pesquisei um pouco sobre o assunto e encontrei apenas projetos muito robustos ou envolvendo aplicativos prontos, que não são interessantes no momento.
Se puderem me ensinar, indicar algum tutorial ou fazer uma recomendação ficaria muito grato.

Answer (score -1):

Podes ler o o que é recebido pelo módulo HC-06, com o Arduíno, como uma entrada de série normal. Um exemplo do código (para ler e escrever) pode ser este:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Define os pinos para comunicação de série (RX, TX)
// Pinos 6 e 7 neste caso
SoftwareSerial MinhaSerial(6,7);
String command = "";

void setup()  
{ 
  // Inicia a comunicação de série com o PC
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  Serial.println("Digite os comandos AT :"); 
  // Inicia a comunicação de série com o módulo BT (portas 6 e 7)
  MinhaSerial.begin(9600); 
} 

void loop() 
{
  // Se o módulo BT tiver bytes para ler
  if (MinhaSerial.available())
  { 
    // Enquanto o módulo BT tiver bytes para ler
    while(MinhaSerial.available())
    {
      // Acrescentar os bytes lidos à variável "comando"
      comando += (char)MinhaSerial.read(); 
    }

    // Deixando o módulo de ter bytes para ler
    // Imprimir a variável "comando" para a interface de série ligada ao PC
    Serial.println(comando);
    // Fazer reset à variável "comando"
    comando = ""; 
  } 

  // Se a interface do PC tiver bytes para ler
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    // Esperar 10ms
    delay(10);
    // Escrever para o módulo BT o que é recebido do PC
    MinhaSerial.write(Serial.read()); 
  } 
}
```

O Arduíno terá de ter 2 interfaces em série, uma para se ligar ao PC e outra ao módulo Bluetooth. Este exemplo foi retirado [daqui](http://buildbot.com.br/blog/configuracao-do-modulo-bluetooth-hc-06-com-arduino/).

Para poderes comunicar com um telemóvel android aconselho-te primeiro a utilizar uma aplicação que funcione como um terminar Bluetooth, como por exemplo a [Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Qwerty.BluetoothTerminal&hl=en).

Depois de conseguires verificar que existe de facto comunicação entre o Arduíno e o android é que deverás (se assim o desejares) criar uma aplicação tua, por exemplo recorrendo ao [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)/[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)/[Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) e ao plugin [BluetoothSerial](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) para ler os dados BT na tua app.

Desta forma, se souberes programação web (JS, HTML e CSS) não precisas programar nativamente em android, o que poderá ser bom para quem está a começar.